# Logarithmic Integral evaluation

Tags: numerical-methods, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I was watching this video explaining the Riemann hypothesis, and there is the use of the Li(x), Logarithmic integral function: https://youtu.be/GEcHgadgOn4

It seems that this integral cannot be evaluated exactly, does this mean one uses numerical methods to calculate things to do with Prime numbers?

Comment: No. $Li(x)$ is not the exact value of $\pi(x)$ , it is just an excellent approximation. So, we would not gain anything if we could compute it exactly. Analytic methods can lead to theorems about prime numbers (best example the prime number theorem) , but then about the distribution of the primes , never concerning concrete primes. They are and keep of course discrete.

Comment: What do you mean by "this integral cannot be evaluated exactly"? Do you think $\log 2$ or $e^2$ can be evaluated "exactly"? By the way the formula in your video is false. The arctan is just an approximation and not the exact value.